# Finding $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1}$$

Book says answer is $2$, though nothing I tried gave me a $2$. I did $y=mx, y=0, x=0$, all ways learned in classes, but only find $0/0$ and $0$ as answers.

Comment: Hint: rationalize the denominator. P.S. Your title doesn't match the question.

Comment: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345262/multivariable-limit-lim-x-y-to-0-0-frac-x2-y2-sqrtx2-y2-1?rq=1) Search better next time

Comment: Oh. So sorry. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rationalize the denominator:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1} $$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(x^2+y^2)\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+1\right)}{x^2+y^2} $$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+1 $$
$$=\sqrt{1}+1 = 2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @dxiv's hint...

Fractions of the form $\frac {a}{\sqrt{b}+c}$ can bedealt with by a process called "rationalising the denominator." It's used in dealing with surds and is similar to the process used to help when dividing by a complex number.

The trick is to multiply the fraction by $\frac {\sqrt{b}-c}{\sqrt{b}-c}$.

The original fraction becomes: $\frac {a({\sqrt{b}-c})}{(\sqrt{b}+c)({\sqrt{b}-c})}=\frac {a({\sqrt{b}-c})}{b-c^2}$

In surds the advantage gained by this method is that the denominator is rational and easy to deal with.

This method can remove a factor in the denominator that would otherwise be $0$,  this removing the difficulty of dividing by zero.